# How do I check if two string arrays are equal?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, classification

I'm trying to make a classification program for different animals. Below is my code (with only one animal as an example). The program is meant to take in user inputs of their answers to each question and then add them to an array (answerList). In this example, if `answerList` (the array containing all the user's inputs) is equal to the `Horse` array, the user will be told their animal is a horse.

However, the last `four lines` of code doesn't work. It produces no final output. Is there anyway to get my below code to work?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim aAquatic, aInsect, aTentacles, aBird, aFlippers, aFly, aHoney, aLegs, aFeline, aStripes, aDomestic, aMilk, aWool, aSnout
    Dim Horse = {“n”, “n”, “n”, “n”, “n,”, "n", “n”, “n”, “n”, “n”, “n”, “n”, “n”, “n”}
    Dim animalArray = {Horse, Cow, Sheep, Pig, Dog, Cat, Lion, Tiger, Dolphin, Seal, Penguin, Ostrich, Sparrow, Bee, Wasp, Termite, Octopus}
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the classification. Choose one of these animals and I will attempt to guess it: horse, cow, sheep, pig, dog, cat, lion, tiger, dolphin, seal, penguin, ostrich, sparrow, bee, wasp, termite, octopus. Click enter to continue.")
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Is your animal aquatic? (y or n)")
    aAquatic = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aAquatic = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aAquatic = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Is your animal an insect? (y or n)")
    aInsect = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aInsect = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aInsect = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Does your animal have tentacles? (y or n)")
    aTentacles = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aTentacles = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aTentacles = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Is your animal a bird? (y or n)")
    aBird = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aBird = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aBird = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Does your animal have flippers? (y or n)")
    aFlippers = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aFlippers = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aFlippers = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Can your animal fly? (y or n)")
    aFly = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aFly = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aFly = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Can your animal make honey? (y or n)")
    aHoney = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aHoney = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aHoney = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Does your animal have two legs? (y or n)")
    aLegs = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aLegs = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aLegs = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Is your animal a feline? (y or n)")
    aFeline = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aFeline = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aFeline = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Does your animal have stripes? (y or n)")
    aStripes = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aStripes = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aStripes = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Is your animal a domestic pet? (y or n)")
    aDomestic = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aDomestic = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aDomestic = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Does your animal produce milk we can drink? (y or n)")
    aMilk = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aMilk = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aMilk = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Does your animal have wool? (y or n)")
    aWool = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aWool = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aWool = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Does your animal have a snout? (y or n)")
    aSnout = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
    If aSnout = "y" Then
        answerList.Add("y")
    ElseIf aSnout = "n" Then
        answerList.Add("n")
    End If
    Console.ReadKey()

    String.Join(", ", answerList)
    String.Join(", ", Horse)
    If answerList Is Horse Then
        Console.WriteLine("Your animal is a horse.")
    End If
```

Comment: I have a solution now, so no worries (:

Comment: As arrays are IEnumerable, you could take a look at [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid creating string just for checking purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I´m not verry familiar with VB.Net, but shouldn´t it be:

```
dim s1 as String = String.Join(", ", answerList)
dim s2 as String = String.Join(", ", Horse)
If s1 = s2 Then
  Console.WriteLine("Your animal is a horse.")
End If
```

And also I can´t find the declaration of answerList:

```
dim answerList as new List(Of String)
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your quick response! I actually made a different error that someone else found that was preventing it from working, but your code also works so thank you for your help.Regarding the declaration of answerList; it's actually in my actual code but for some reason I forgot to add it in on here!

Answer (score -1):

Probably would help if you got rid of the comma in the first array. Can't really compare the two arrays if that's in there...